# How to rewrite Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, table-rates, carrier

I would overwrite **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php** with my custom component. My code:

> app/etc/modules/Infocurci_Shipping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Infocurci_Shipping>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Infocurci_Shipping>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Infocurci/Shipping/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Infocurci_Shipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Infocurci_Shipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <carrier_tablerate>Infocurci_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate</carrier_tablerate>
                </rewrite>
            <shipping>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Infocurci/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php

```
<?php
class Infocurci_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate
{

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
       die('this is only a test');
    }

}
```

What's wrong? I do not see my code in action.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong. The function `collectRates()` allready exists in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php.` Your custom `Template.php` file only extends it, not overriding it.

You can try to copy `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` and change the `collectionRates()` function in there.

Comment: I know its a year later, but I've tried your suggestion, and even tried copying the entire shipping folder to local/mage, but its refusing to overwrite the system.xml. Cache is turned off. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the declaration of your own model (?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Infocurci_Shipping>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Infocurci_Shipping>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <shipping>
            <rewrite>
                <carrier_tablerate>Infocurci_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate</carrier_tablerate>
            </rewrite>
        <shipping>
        <infocurci_shipping>
            <class>Infocurci_Shipping_Model</class>
        </infocurci_shipping>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```